# Is there a way to use a generic Spring Data JPA repository implementation?

Tags: java, spring, generics, spring-data-jpa, jhipster

I'm setting up a new Spring Boot API with 100+ entities (using [JHipster](https://www.jhipster.tech/)) and my question is: given I have a set of repository-layer methods I want all my repositories to be able to call these methods.

I've already tried to make all `.*Repository` interfaces to extend `.*RepositoryQuery` ('RepositoryQuery' is my default custom interface name suffix), then implemented those interfaces with an entity-specific `.*RepositoryQueryImpl` class. Note that all the `.*RepositoryQueryImpl` classes extends a generic-implementation class, named `BaseRepositoryQueryImpl`.

Please note that the '.*' in given regexes stands for any entity in my persistent entity set.

Shown code below with key classes and interfaces:

1. My Super interface

```java
public interface BaseRepositoryQuery<T, PK> {
   public List<T> retrieveByCriteria(T searchCriteria);
   // other methods go here ...
}
```

2. My Super implementation

```java
public class BaseRepositoryQueryImpl<T, PK> implements BaseRepositoryQuery<T, PK> {
   @PersistenceContext
   private EntityManager em;

   private Class<T> businessClass;

   protected BaseRepositoryQueryImpl(Class<T> businessClass) {
     this.businessClass = businessClass;
   }

   public List<T> retrieveByCriteria(T searchCriteria) {
     // ...
   }
   // other methods go here ...
}
```

3. An entity's `RepositoryQuery` interface:

```java
public interface SomeEntityRepositoryQuery extends BaseRepositoryQuery<SomeEntity, Long> {}
```

4. An entity's repository implementation:

```java
public class SomeEntityRepositoryQueryImpl extends BaseRepositoryQueryImpl<SomeEntity, Long> implements SomeEntityRepositoryQuery {

 public SomeEntityRepositoryQueryImpl(Class<SomeEntity> businessClass) {
   super(businessClass);
 }

 public SomeEntityRepositoryQueryImpl() {
   super(SomeEntity.class);
 }
}
```

5. An entity `Repository` interface:

```java
@Repository
public interface SomeEntityRepository extends SomeEntityRepositoryQuery, JpaRepository<SomeEntity, Long> {
  // other methods go here...
}
```

6. Then, the idea is that I'd inject some entity repository bean like this (in an Spring controller or service):

```java
@Autowired
  private SomeEntityRepository someEntityRepository;
```

Please note that 'SomeEntity' could be any entity of my set of persistent entities (sorry for being so obvious). Furthermore, I've already set my configuration as:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories("<my base jpa repositories package here>")
```

So far, all I've got (running maven) is an error log:

```
... bunch of lines here...
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
 Error creating bean with name 'agentServicesImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'agentRepository'; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'agentRepository': 
Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.lang.Object 

br.ufpa.labes.spm.repository.interfaces.BaseRepositoryQuery.retrieveBySecondaryKey(java.lang.String)! No property retrieveBySecondaryKey found for type Agent!
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:596)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:90)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:374)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1411)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:592)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:845)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:877)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:742)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:389)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:311)
        at br.ufpa.labes.spm.SpmApp.main(SpmApp.java:63)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
... here too ...
```

I suspect that the error could be related to Spring repositories naming and I've already tried to look in other SO threads, but none that fit in this context.

Answer (score 0):

Please check in BaseRepositoryQuery.. incorrect field you might be using. That's why its complaining about that.

Comment: So all of my methods should be related to entities fields, right? So it means that I could not use any name for interface methods?